# Frame around R code and output in knitr and Latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am using knitr and Latex to write an intro into and overview of R. How can I get a box around R code chunks and R output in Latex? I can get them when using R Markdown and knitr to generate HTML. The Sweave way to frame chunks with a box does not work with knitr.
Thanks and regards,
Andreas

Comment: Sweave uses the *fancyvrb* LaTeX package, so I'd look into the help for that and include the relevant options in your Sweave file's preamble, after loading `sweave.sty` in imported.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do it with Sweave. Now I'm looking for a way to get a similar effect purely with knitr.

Comment: Sorry, misread the Q. Just to confirm, you want a plain knitr solution for knitr -> LaTeX?

Comment: sorry in case this was unclear. Yes, I'd like a pure knitr solution.

Comment: Boxes are less visually appealing than shading in my eyes, but I can be very biased. It is possible to redefine the LaTeX environments, just like what I did for listings: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/listings/ and all the gory details are here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/hooks-latex.R (sorry I do not have time for a complete answer)

Comment: Thanks Yihui (also for the great work on knitr in general!)